# autocomplete is broken in Eclipse Latest May upgrade with JAva 6?

Tags: java, android

I have a PC right now which have installed Java in July 2011. When i run my latest download ADT it's work without anything required (I thing they take old installed Java).

Now My trouble is I never see autocomplete. After too many CTRL + Space I got autocomplete but never in Java files.

I found that their is AVD already crated for Android 1.6. Look like someone have used Android Eclipse on computer before.

I not want to know what have used in current PC. I just want to run my latest downloaded ADT which not have any kind of code completion when I work on Java files.

I have deleted the workspace folder and it's not useful. Do someone guide us what to do.

I hear in Another answer here (Raghav sood) that Android use Java 6. Do this means it will work. I thing it's about Android use Java 6's customized package not Java 6.

What I need to do now to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just download this bundle:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Or try the new Android Studio, which still on beta, released at Google I/O 2013:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Comment: The bundle is the way to go. It includes everything in one zipfile.

Comment: @ROI thanks for your answer. Actually it's have issue with the old .android file that is written in user folder. I delete it and it's work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If I were in your shoes, I would download and install the latest version of Java, Eclipse and the ADT.

Of Course there could be an other solution, but in my opinion its the fastest way. And you get some bugs fixed with the new version. 2 Years are a long time in android development.

EDIT: Some advice: If you've installed all these things, just zip it so in case your eclipse is broken you've a fast backup.

Comment: I have deleted the .android folder (this make trouble) and update the Java. now everything work fine :)